# Font weight when active - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I am trying to make the selected list item STAY bold after selected and go back to normal after a different item is selected. basically I want a "currently selected tab". is there a way I can do this with css or do I need Javascript? Here is my code ->

CSS: (using SASS)

```
   .setup-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  font-size: 18px;
  color: $base-link-color;
  text-align: left;

  li {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;

    &.active {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="setup-nav">
  <li><a href="#install-http">HTTP</a></li>
  <li><a href="#install-email">Email</a></li>
  <li><a href="#install-ruby">Ruby</a></li>
  <li><a href="#install-python">Python</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hopefully there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: You will need javascript to inject "active" into the class attribute of the active LI

Comment: Okay Thanks! not too bad. Do you have an example of that by chance?

Comment: You should clarify that your CSS is actually SASS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(".setup-nav").on( "click", "li", function(){ // attach to Click event
    $(".setup-nav li.active").removeClass("active"); // reset all <li> to no active class
    $(this).addClass("active"); // add active class to this <li> only
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ reference for use of `.on()`

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ reference for use of `.addClass()`

Someone may come along with pure JavaScript answer (no jQuery library use) if you prefer that approach.

Comment: This is great but when the page first loads nothing is highlighted? how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a default tab easily identified on first page load? You could use: `$(".setup-nav li").eq( X ).addClass("active");` where `X` is an integer between 0 and 3 corresponding to list items 1-4. Another option would be to use `<li class="active">` in your HTML.